# syntax error at or near "GENERATED" with debezium/postgres container

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, ef-code-first, kafka-consumer-api, debezium

I want to create app using debezium and kafka with dotnet core app. Kafka, postgres, zookeper and connector running on docker without problem. I tried to this coomand **dotnet ef database update --project Kafka.Consumer.Api --verbose** and I got error

```
Failed executing DbCommand (10ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='20']
    CREATE TABLE "Products" (
        "Id" integer GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 100),
        "Name" text NOT NULL,
        "Price" double precision NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT "PK_Products" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
    );
    Disposing transaction.
    Closing connection to database 'HelloWorld' on server 'tcp://127.0.0.1:5431'.
    Closed connection to database 'HelloWorld' on server ''.
    'KafkaConsumerDbContext' disposed.
    Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42601: syntax error at or near "GENERATED"

    POSITION: 44
       at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|213_0(NpgsqlConnector connector, Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
      Exception data:
        Severity: ERROR
        SqlState: 42601
        MessageText: syntax error at or near "GENERATED"
        Position: 44
        File: scan.l
        Line: 1127
        Routine: scanner_yyerror
    42601: syntax error at or near "GENERATED"

    POSITION: 44
```

My docker-compose file

```
    version: '3.7'

services:

  postgres:
    image: debezium/postgres
    container_name: postgres
    networks: 
      - broker-kafka
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: fatih
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
    ports:
      - 5431:5432
      
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    container_name: zookeeper
    networks: 
      - broker-kafka
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka
    networks: 
      - broker-kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_LOG_CLEANER_DELETE_RETENTION_MS: 5000
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS: 1

  connector:
    image: debezium/connect:latest
    container_name: kafka_connect_with_debezium
    networks: 
      - broker-kafka
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      GROUP_ID: 1
      CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_configs
      OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_offsets
      BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:29092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka

  kafdrop:
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop:latest
    container_name: kafdrop
    networks: 
      - broker-kafka
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: kafka:29092

networks: 
  broker-kafka:
    driver: bridge
```

After I googled this error i saw the problem is postgresql version . What should i do? Should i change Npgsql (v6.0.2) nuget package version or whatever ?

Comment: What is your Postgres version? `select version();` will tell you

Comment: where should i write this command?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i searched on docker hub. **This image is based upon postgres:11-apline and adds two logical decoding plug-ins**

Comment: `select` statement are run in a SQL client (e.g. `psql`) that is connected to the database in question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i run this command and i saw my psql version 9.6.22. And i solved by changing docker image verison -> image: debezium/postgres:15-alpine